# Prevent background video from freezing when not in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a website I'm developing with the help of somebody, and I have two background videos. The problem is that they stop playing when not being looked at in the viewport after a few seconds. This ruins the user experience a bit as they still appear to be paused even when entering the viewport again. You then have to scroll away and back to it in order to kickstart it into playing again.

Is there a way that the video can start playing again when it gets close to being in the viewport so it looks like it has never stopped? Or running all the time, (not sure if this is wise or not)

[Website so far](http://dev.matthewbugeja.com/)

Comment: It seems that your code is fine but the video file is corrupted, says Firefox. When you play it directly by pasting the video url in the browser it stop playing after a few seconds (with the webm format at least). Try with another video just to see it it's the problem and if so, make a new video file. Maybe a problem occured during the first video export :)

Comment: Thanks :) With the infinite possibilities in coding, I wouldn't have thought to check if it was the video itself. I'll try re-rendering a video. Cheers.